# TextInputEditText error when running acitivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #107: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText

This is my gradle build :

```
dependencies {

implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.12'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
```

**XML File**

```
      <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/loginEtEmailLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_round_white"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textLogin"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/loginEtPasswordLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:hintEnabled="false"
        app:errorEnabled="false"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/loginEtEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:hint="@string/Login_Email"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_mail_outline_black_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**My emulator API is 19**.

please help me, i'm still newbie in android programming, ThankYou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that in your xml you use `android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText` and not plain `TextInputEditText`  
Edit: check the drwable if it is in the drawable folder and not in say `drawable(v24)`

Comment: hmm, i'm sure that i use android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText but still error...

Comment: then post your xml

Comment: there is my xml heheh

Comment: what is " drawable(v24) " mean ?

Comment: Thank you very much, i try to remove the drawable xml that contain (v24) like "ic_email.xml(v24)"  to  "ic_email.xml" , and it works for me :D

Comment: @snblade123456 if it worked check it as the right answer